# Infinite While that dosen't lock up thread

Tags: loops, while-loop

How can I make a while loop that does something every second that doesn't freeze the application? For example using Thread.Sleep() freezes the thread. Does anyone know?

Comment: If you call sleep from the main thread, it will stop the main thread. You need to create another thread to do work.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Your Statement goes here

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test= new Test();
    Thread t= new Thread(test);
    t.start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify language.
I'll provide a sample in c++, the concept should be similar in other languages.

First, this will put the main thread to sleep:

```
int main(int, char**)
{
  while(true)
  { 
    sleep(1); // Put current thread to sleep;
    // do some work.

  }
  return 0;
}
```

This on the other hand will create a worker thread. The main thread will remain active.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void doWork()
{
   while(true) 
   {
      // Do some work;
      sleep(1); // Rest
      std::cout << "hi from worker." << std::endl;
   }
}

int main(int, char**)
{

  std::thread worker(&doWork);
  std::cout << "hello from main thread, the worker thread is busy." << std::endl;
  worker.join();

  return 0;
}
```

<strike>The code is untested.</strike> Just tested this, see it in action: http://ideone.com/aEVFi

Requires c++11 for thread. Also, note that in the above code, the main thread will wait for join infinitely because the worker thread never terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Put your loop and Thread.Sleep() in a worker thread.